# Replacing the number in a string

Tags: c#-4.0

if my string is lets say "Alfa1234Beta"
how can I convert all the number in to "_"
for example "Alfa1234Beta"
will be "Alfa____Beta"

Answer (score 1):

Going with the Regex approach pointed out by others is possibly OK for your scenario. Mind you however, that Regex sometimes tend to be overused. A hand rolled approach could be like this:

```
    static string ReplaceDigits(string str)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Char.IsDigit(str[i]))
            {
                if (sb == null)
                {
                    // Seen a digit, allocate StringBuilder, copy non-digits we might have skipped over so far.
                    sb = new StringBuilder();
                    if (i > 0)
                    {
                        sb.Append(str, 0, i);
                    }
                }
                // Replace current character (a digit)
                sb.Append('_');
            }
            else
            {
                if (sb != null)
                { 
                    // Seen some digits (being replaced) already. Collect non-digits as well.
                    sb.Append(str[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        if (sb != null)
        {
            return sb.ToString();
        }
        return str;
    }
```

It is more light weight than Regex and only allocates when there is actually something to do (replace). So, go ahead use the Regex version if you like. If you figure out during profiling that is too heavy weight, you can use something like the above. YMMV

Answer (score 0):

You can run for loop on the string and then use the following method to replace numbers with _

if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(i, "^[0-9]*$"))

Here variable i is the character in the for loop .

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
var s = "Alfa1234Beta";
var s2 = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(s, "[0-9]", "_");
```

s2 now contains "Alfa____Beta".

Explanation: the regex `[0-9]` matches any digit from 0 to 9 (inclusive). The Regex.Replace then replaces all matched characters with an "_".

**EDIT**
And if you want it a bit shorter AND also match non-latin digits, use `\d` as a regex:

```
var s = "Alfa1234Beta๓"; // ๓ is "Thai digit three"
var s2 = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(s, @"\d", "_");
```

s2 now contains "Alfa____Beta_".